# Regelation, ice cutting, and snowballs

Tags: pressure, phase-transition

Pressure decreases the melting point of ice, and applying pressure then releasing it will allow ice blocks to weld together by melting them and letting them freeze. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQCVnjGUv24).

The detractors of this hypothesis claim that the pressure is 100 atm per degree C and thus too much to make it significant. Instead, the ice contact [cold welds](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137552/cold-welding-of-a-metallic-surface). Also, the warm room could help the metal wire melt through.

But reglaton isn't completely invalid. In the ice block case, the temperature of the ice is almost exactly 0 (the block is in a warm room and melting), so tiny temperature differences of 0.01C may be significant. For snowballs, the contact pressure is much higher than the hand-pressure because materials [have much less contact area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperity_%28materials_science%29) on a nanoscopic scale. In these "everyday" examples, what is the more important effect, regelation or welding?

To test this we could run experiments with a material like dodecane (melts at -10C), which contracts when freezing so does not show regelation.

Comment: [This paper](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/332/1588/51) probably answers it for anyone with the time to read it.